# How does kafka share disk space among brokers with different storage size?

Tags: apache-kafka

How would kafka react to following scenarios?

1. I have 2 brokers, with both different configuration (CPU/RAM), how is the load distributed among the 2 brokers? Equally?
2. I have 2 brokers, with both different storage size, 100 GB and 200 GB, how would kafka broker share the disk space among them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage space doesn't determine load. The default partitioner will perform round-robin distribution on its own, and partition assignment is also fairly balanced, AFAIK.

However, your storage space will be limited by the smallest broker because partitions must be replicated across them in full (assuming you use replication factor > 1, which you should).

Comment: So, it makes no sense to use 2 brokers with different CPU power, eventually, it is going to be round-robin distribution

Comment: I thought we were talking about storage, not CPU? Or RAM or network, for that fact.

Comment: But if one broker has a better CPU (and other overall specs), you can consume and produce to it faster, but your other brokers will still be slow and lag, so I don't see the point.

Comment: Apologies, Question was not clear. If Small CPU broker uses 60% RAM/CPU and large CPU broker uses 40% RAM/CPU, will Kafka maintain the RAM/CPU usage evenly?

Comment: There is no tight correlation between memory usage and storage (other than more index files requires more memory to manage them). If you want to assign a higher workload to a certain partition of a broker, you need to write a partitioner that'll do so